# How to place sign here docusign tag in document dynamically

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am using Docusign for Salesforce for signing documents. I download the pre-filled document from other system which has a separate column for signature which is labelled as 'Applicant's Signature'. I upload the document as attachment on record detail page in salesforce. I would like that when agent clicks the 'send with docusign' custom button 'Sign Here' tab gets automatically added by identifying the existing text(Applicant's Signature) from the document.

FYI, I have already seen that it is possible when we place autoplace/anchor text(such as \s1) in document. Any recommendation around adding 'sign here' tab by recognizing the text within the document? Also, I have hidden both the screens which appears after clicking the 'send with docusign' button so agents will not be able to use creating custom tag and drag/drop. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Are you using the REST API or Docusign for Salesforce ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, as stated in first line of the question i am not using rest api but docusign for salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

You can create signHere tab by two ways.

1. By X and Y coordinate
2. By mentioning the anchor tex

If you are using REST API, your JSON will look like

```
"recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "xPosition": "100",
                    "yPosition": "100",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }],
                "initialHereTabs": [{
                    "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:",
                    "anchorXOffset": "1",
                    "anchorYOffset": "0",
                    "anchorUnits": "inches"
                }]
            }
        }]
}
```